# Java: Structure a users control system using OOP

Tags: java, swing, oop, class

I hope I can explain.

I don't have a problem, just I want to know how to build my users system control and I want to know if my idea is correct:

My idea:

*One class (file 1) to functions, methods and operations

*Other class (file 2) to swing elements, buttons, textbox, etc.

*But I don't know how connect these two classes.

For example:: I have 2 textbox (user, password) and one button, then when press the button, send data of each textbox(file 2) to a function (file 1) and process.

If you have any other choice, I'd read it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: There are lots of ways this is done. For desktop applications (no remote servers), Model-View-Controller (MVC) is very popular. Consider taking a look at [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462964/mvc-do-i-need-to-use-controller-in-the-view/12463551#12463551). (This can also be used for self-contained web applications, but this isn't Swing at that point.)

Comment: Just remember that OO-ness usually entails telling an object what to do, and the object does it itself.  Not doing it for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern to solve your problem. Basically, your view (the swing files) only know how to display content, and let the user of the class (the controller) subscribe to receive notifications when the content is changed (this is done with swing listeners). When the content is changed the controller can act on it, modify the model if necessary and also update the view (again, using methods provided by the view).

The GUI should never involve functionality. It should only have code that is used to display what you want. This helps create a better architecture.